# "For today" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

How do we translate these phrases into Spanish: **for the day**, **for the weekend**, etc.? Here's the context:

**The bank has already closed for the day.**

**The schools will shortly be closing for the weekend.**

Here's my attempt:

**El banco ya está cerrado para el día.**

Am I wrong? What would be the most appropriate way to say this in Latin American Spanish (particularly Mexican or Colombian)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El banco ya está cerrado por el día.** (more accurate)

**El banco ya está cerrado por el día de hoy.**

**El banco ya está cerrado por hoy.**

---

**Las escuelas pronto estarán cerrando por el fin de semana.** (more accurate)

**Las escuelas pronto estarán cerrando por este fin de semana.**

(Chilean Spanish)

Comment: Here in Spain we would say "durante" insead of "por": "Pronto las escuelas cerrarán durante el fin de semana".

Comment: Being nice here and answering an ill-posed question (in this case asking translations) has two faces: you are being nice to the OP but you are not being nice to us, which want to keep this site running with good quality questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have other translations:

**El banco ya está cerrado por hoy.**

**El banco ya ha sido cerrado por el día.**

---

**Las escuelas cerrarán pronto por el fin de semana.**

**Las escuelas se cerrarán pronto por el fin de semana.**